# Can you compile C++ header files with clang-cl that have a .h extension?

Tags: visual-c++, clang

I'm trying to compile C++ header files with a `.h` extension using `clang-cl`.  I was able to accomplish this with `clang` using the argument `-x c++-header`.
Is it possible to do this same thing with `clang-cl`?  Here are the three approaches I tried after reading both the [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) and [msvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=vs-2019) argument documentation.

1. Pass no special arguments to the compiler.  This did not work as the files were treated as `c` files rather than `cpp` files.
2. Using the `/TP` argument which "Specifies all source files are C++." This did not work as the files were treated as `cpp` files rather than `cpp headers`.  So things like `#pragma once` did not work.  Note we could work around this problem by using header guards, and this will be our fallback approach if need be.
3. There are `clang-cl` arguments, `-Xclang` and `-mllvm`, which forward arguments straight through to clang/llvm.  I tried `-Xclang -x c++-header`, `-Xclang -x -Xclang c++-header`, `-mllvm -x c++-header`, and `-mllvm -x -mllvm c++-header`, but it seems the decision to compile `c` vs `cpp` happens before the forwarded arguments are considered by clang/llvm, so this approach did not work either.

We don't want to change the existing file extensions if those are relevant, since those would be API changes.

If you're asking why - I'm aware this may be unconventional but we have our reasons for doing this.  We are using clang libtooling in order to get an AST for our C++ interface, to code generate bindings for other languages.  We compile the public header files because we don't care about anything else.

Comment: As a workaround, if we change all out files to use header guards instead of #pragma once, that will work.  Still looking for a solution requiring no code changes however.

Comment: Be sure to distinguish `/TP` and `/Tp <filename>`.  The latter works just fine on any file, including .h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
clang-cl /clang:-xc++-header <your .h file>
```